# Create a vector with 100 places

Tags: r

I have this code and I want to calculate  a vector `x` `for 1 to 100`, however, it shows me a vector with 99 zeros and the last one `x[100]` a value. How can it return all the vector elements?

```
sum1<-function(r,n){return(sum(r^(1:n)))}
sum2<-function(r,n){return((r^(n+1)-1)/(r-1)-1)} 

    print("the the result for 10 20 30 40 ")


for (i in seq(10,40,10)){
 a<-sum1(1.08,i)
 b<-sum2(1.08,i)

print( a )
print( b )

c<-a-b print(  c) }
x<-vector("numeric",length(1:100))
for(i in 100){x[i]<-sum1(1.08,i)   }  

print(x)
```

Comment: Bit unclear what you want ... but the final loop, if you want all the value use `for(i in 1:100)`. As it is, it just goes to the 100th index

Comment: yes but it shows me that x[1]  is 0 ..........x[99]=0  only x[100] =29683.28

Comment: Voting to close, as a typo